# Determine whether in an interactive session vs non-interactive session (ie. scp) within ssh rc

Tags: ssh

I have my ssh rc (`~/.ssh/rc`)on a remote machine setup to start `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` any public keys present. When I try and `scp` to this machine, it will attempt to prompt for the pass keys, then the `scp` will fail and exit.

Ideally, I would like the `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to only occur for interactive ssh sessions. Is there a way in the ssh rc to determine whether the session is interactive and selectively run (or not run) certain commands in response?

Comment: What specific rc file do you mean by "my ssh rc"? Do you mean [.ssh/rc](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#SSHRC)? or something like `.bashrc`?

Comment: I mean `.ssh/rc`.

Comment: Have you tried `if [ -t 0 ]; then …` or `if tty > /dev/null; then …`? P.S. [O’Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ssh-the-secure/0596008953/ch08s04.html) was literally the first result when I did [a Google search for “ssh rc”](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+rc).

Comment: @Scott I did when I was originally looking for `.ssh/rc` information, but ended up following a different tutorial. Thanks for the pointer, I'll see if that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the environment variable `SSH_TTY` is set. See [how to distinguish ssh from scp in ~/.ssh/rc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657250/how-to-distinguish-ssh-from-scp-in-ssh-rc)

.